# Import error in tensorflow in jupyter notebook ( import tensorflow_io as tfio )

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, project

import tensorflow_io as tfio   I'm getting an error with this code for a deep learning project of audio classifier , can someone help me out?

project from nicholes renotte yt channel , issues with tensor_io code in jupyter notebook .